# How to execute UPDATE query with JOIN and ORDER?

Tags: mysql, sql

my query is:

```
set @csum := 0;
update `aaa` INNER JOIN
       `bbb`
       ON `bbb`.`id`=`aaa`.`tid`
    set `aaa`.`tc` = (@csum := @csum + 1)
    WHERE `aaa`.`tid` IN (6,7)
    ORDER BY `bbb`.`priority` ASC,  `aaa`.`floor` ASC, `aaa`.`id` ASC;
```

but return error  `#1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY`

How can i execute this query?
i need sort and update from first to last record

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What do you need the order by for?

Comment: for sort before update

Comment: i need sort and update from first record to last record

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see how to give a good minimal and complete example. You also learn more when you have to explain where you are heading to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite tricky.  MySQL doesn't allow `order by` with an `update` that uses a `join`.  But, your query needs both tables for the `order by`.

The following select seems to return what you want:

```
select aaa.*, (@csum := @csum + 1) as csum
from `aaa` join
     `bbb`
     on `bbb`.`id` = `aaa`.`tid` cross join
     (select @csum := 0) params
where `aaa`.`tid` IN (6, 7)
order by `bbb`.`priority` ASC,  `aaa`.`floor` ASC, `aaa`.`id` ASC;
```

You can now incorporate this into an `update`:

```
update aaa join
       (select aaa.*, (@csum := @csum + 1) as csum
        from `aaa` join
             `bbb`
             on `bbb`.`id` = `aaa`.`tid` cross join
             (select @csum := 0) params
        where `aaa`.`tid` IN (6, 7)
        order by `bbb`.`priority` ASC,  `aaa`.`floor` ASC, `aaa`.`id` ASC
      ) aaaa
      on aaaa.id = aaa.id
    set `aaa`.`tc` = csum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set @csum = 0;
update set aaa.tc = (@csum + 1),@csum=@csum+1
from aaa  INNER JOIN bbb  ON bbb.id=aaa.tid  WHERE aaa.tid IN (6,7)
```

and i don't think so order by is required in the case of **update**.